# Tuning vim's less.sh: enabling persistent search history

Tags: vim, history, less, file-search

So, I'm using `vim`'s `less.sh` in place of standard `less` pager:

```
alias less=/usr/share/vim/vim81/macros/less.sh
```

However, I have a major and a minor problem with it.

The major issue is that it does not save searches history. If I open a file with `less.sh`, search for some strings, they are not persisted to the next `less.sh` invocation. Instead, they are discarded, and the history gathered by regular `vim` invocations is used. Is there a way to turn on search history persistence in `less.sh`?

The minor issue is that `less.sh` does not allow opening the same file twice, i.e., it will try creating a `.swp` file and complain that the file is already being edited. This despite the fact that `less.sh` does not allow any modification to the file being viewed, i.e., it does not edit. I would expect it to be stateless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The search history will be stored in `:help 'viminfo'`

You need to edit `less.sh` or copy it (define a new alias) and add `|set viminfo='50,/50` to the end of both lines. You also have to change the encapsulating quotes to `"` since viminfo uses `'` for this `--cmd` string. So we don't have to do any ugly backslash escape.

```sh
vim --cmd 'let no_plugin_maps = 1' -c "runtime! macros/less.vim|set viminfo='50,/50"
```

- `'50` is number of marks remembered (it's required in defining viminfo)
- `/50` is the search history

I guess you could also modify `macros/less.vim`, to avoid the override `|set viminfo='50,/50`

In `runtime/macros/less.vim` at approximately [line 45](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/macros/less.vim#L45)

```
set viminfo=
```

Is the line that clears the `'viminfo'` setting, normally saved by Vim defaults.

Comment: I have added `set viminfo='50,/50` and `set noswapfile` to my `/usr/share/vim/vim81/macros/less.vim` and both of my issues went away! Thank you.